# submit two ajax forms on single page using rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have to separate forms on my page that are similar in that I create a comment via ajax with each.

Not functioning quite right as they are both using the same create.js.erb file.

How would I separate them so that they only render the appropriate jQuery code?

**Index:**

*Form #1*

```
<% form_for(@snapshot_comment, :html => { :class => "snapshot_comment", :id => "snapshot_comment" } do |f| %>
Some stuff
<% end %>
<ol id="snapshot_comments_collection">
Append stuff here...
</ol>
```

*Form #2*

```
<% form_for(@photo_comment, :html => { :class => "section-photo-comments", :id => "section-photo-comments" } do |f| %>
Some stuff
<% end %>
<ol id="comments-collection">
Append stuff here...
</ol>
```

**Controller:**

```
# POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.commentable.authorize(params[:auth_key])
    unauthorized! unless can? :create, @comment
        if @comment.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to(request.headers["Referer"]) }
          format.js
          format.json {
          render :json => @comment, :status => :created, :location => @comment
          }
        end
         else
        redirect_to(request.headers["Referer"])
          end
  end
```

**Create.js.erb**:

```
$j("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment)) %>").prependTo("#snapshot_comments_collection");
$j('#snapshot_comment')[0].reset();

$j("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment)) %>").prependTo("#comments-collection");
$j('#section-photo-comments')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `$()` but I fail to see any use of `:remote => true` for your forms?  Do paste the log of your rails (dev) server.